# Unknown wifi network

Tags: network, wifi

I have a new unknown wifi network with a full signal in my home. My nearest neighbors are a substantial distance away and this network has a full signal.

It is only detectable when my desktop is turned on. My desktop shows it as a LAN connection named DIRECT-DRHOMEmsXC.
Wifi analyzer says -32dbm 2437 Mhz(20Mhz)0.2m.

What could it possibly be?

Comment: Is it still there if you turn off all power for your home?

Comment: It does not show up on my desk top. Only on my mobile devices. I installed a wifi analyzer and it is almost as strong as my home signal.

Comment: I have not cut power to my home.

Comment: What is the SSID and the actual sig strength? Do you have access to wifi sniffing tools?

Comment: It is only detectable when my desk top is turned on. My desktop shows it as a LAN connection named DIRECT-DRHOMEmsXC. I am most certainly not a tech expert, so all information is greatly appreciated. Wifi analyzer says -32dbm 2437 Mhz(20Mhz)0.2m. Thanks so much.

Comment: do you have a printer with wifi-direct? That could be the Case

Answer (score 1):

This might be a SoftAP or Wi-Fi Direct, some "smart-devices" (Not sure what word to use) that can connect to the internet comes with a this feature to redistribute your internet or to create an ad-hoc connection.

For examples some TV's

[image: LG TV]

Or Roku streaming devices

[image]

In your case it's a Wi-Fi Direct because of the SSID you provided. Check the configuration of something new you just bought maybe?